# Angular2 custom attribute not appearing in DOM after binding

Tags: data-binding, angular, attributes

I am trying to use Angular2 to build a [WiX](https://dev.wix.com/) component.

I added the WiX custom attribute `wix-options` to a `span`, using Angular's syntax to allow binding (note the `{{'email' | translate}}`):

```
<span wix-ctrl="Input" attr.wix-options="{placeholder: {{'email' | translate}}, size: 'big'}"></span>
```

When I single-step the JavaScript code in Chrome, the attribute does not appear on the element:
[image]

The `wix-ctrl` attribute, which was not prefixed with `attr.` to allow binding, continues to appear.

How can I make Angular2 preserve the `wix-options` attribute in the DOM? The WiX UI library searches for the elements tagged with `wix-ctrl` and then reads the `wix-options` to get more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try doing that the directive way:

```
<span wix-ctrl="Input" [attr.wix-options]="{placeholder: {{'email' | translate}}, size: 'big'}"></span>
```

Otherwise you'd have to do it something like:

```
<span wix-ctrl="Input" attr.wix-options="{{ {placeholder: {{'email' | translate}}, size: 'big'} }}"></span>
```

Since you are passing in an object, Angular isn't aware that it should parse the whole thing or not.  You're probably getting an error in Dev Tools, too.

Comment: I actually tried that earlier, even though I did not state it in the question. I got the same result. BTW, Angular does **not** appear to have a problem parsing the attribute value as shown. I assume that it uses some kind of pattern matching (regexp?) to find the `{{`.

Comment: I wonder if has something to do with the order things are parsing.  I've not used WiX, so I'm not sure exactly how it works, but I'm assuming it parses the -options to create some custom DOM objects.  Maybe it's attempting to parse the options before Angular has had a change to parse/process it's part.

Comment: I am playing with jquery to try to "inject" the `wix-options` attribute without using Angular binding. If it works, I'll post an answer as a kludgy solution until someone posts a better one.